# new grass seed experiment: sun vs shade

Tags: grass, germination

I planted some Kentucky Bluegrass under a group of trees and it germinated non-uniformly
with many patches (each patch is roughly 10 inches in diameter).  Can this be caused
just by "complete sun" vs "complete shade" differences?  I did not use mulch to cover
the seed, so one alternative likely explanation is that my watering has washed away
much of the seed leaving patches where seed accumulated (even though I tried to be
gentle, watering three times a day for a week adds up!).

I was hoping to find some research in which someone plants grass seed under a
checkerboard screen of sun and shade (a time lapse video over the first month of this
would be great!), but am surprised that I can't find any.  What would happen?  My
feeling is that it will germinate fine everywhere, but then have limited growth
(e.g., about 1 inch) in the shade squares.

By the way, [the Kentucky Bluegrass I used is designed for dense shade](https://www.scotts.com/en-us/products/grass-seed/scotts-turf-builder-grass-seed-dense-shade-mix).

Comment: Kentucky Bluegrass has always been a full-sun/mostly sun grass, so seeing that you have a "designer" version for shade is intriguing. Please update your question with some details on the variety you used - for example, the variety's name and the name of the company that released it would be very helpful in both answering this question and for future reference for other users.

Comment: @Jurp Ok. I added the product link into my question.

Comment: Well,that's a mix, not straight bluegrass, It's US law to include a tag on the bag that shows the percentage of each variety. I'm guessing the mix contains a majority of Fescues + Perennial Ryegrass. Please post the percentages. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. I read some of the reviews and they talk about very quick germination and quick growth. That would not be Kentucky bluegrass (germination is 21 days). It could be annual ryegrass, which would be very bad. We did have a poster earlier this year who used a Scott's mix that was 25% or so annual ryegrass, which caused him problems. I hope that this is NOT the case for you. Scott's seeds, BTW, are over-rated and over-priced, but there's no way you'd know if you weren't in the trade.

Comment: @Jurp You're right, it's mixed, but I think I could have asked the same question for ryegrass or bluegrass.  Anyway, I experimented with two other pure (well at least >50%) Kentucky Bluegrass brands a month ago too with similar patchy results, so I decided to specify Kentucky Bluegrass.  But, the latest mix that I used was that Scotts product in the link.  Anyway, I'd be happy with an answer for either grass type, if you know how the checkerboard experiment would go...

Comment: How long ago did you plant the seed? Did you cover the seed with topsoil?

Comment: @Jurp The latest section was planted 3 weeks ago (but other sections planted even earlier remain patchy too).  I guess there is some chance they will fill in (though my case seems to be worse than the "sprout and pout" cases I see) over time or just because the temperature will cool off (maybe I planted too early in the summer heat...everyone says to plant later in the fall, but I thought I could compensate by watering a lot, and because it's already very shady).

Comment: Grass seeds need to be covered by a thin layer of topsoil or, more commonly, straw or cheesecloth (depending on the size of the area planted) to have optimum germination. If you're seeding into existing grass, then it's usually covered with sifted soil or sand, if at all. What varieties are included in your mix? Kentucky Bluegrass takes at least three weeks to germinate, so you may still be okay (although once sprouted, it may die in the shade, so be aware of that).

Comment: @Jurp It was covered with a thin layer of topsoil, but of course it is not perfect and much seed winds up uncovered. The main varieties I've used is Kentucky Bluegrass (and some attempts also included ryegrass per our above comments, but all results were unfortunately patchy). So, do heavily shaded areas never germinate? or do they germinate but not grow much like I suggested in my question? Knowing this would help me determine the cause of my patchiness.

Comment: The mix you used will have contained Kentucky bluegrass, perennial ryegrass, fescues of various kinds and (I hope not) possible annual ryegrass. The fact that Scott's doesn't list the varieties on the website is not a good thing. If you still have a partial bag of seed, please list the varieties and percentages. What is in the mix makes a huge difference with your success. It also sounds like you made several attempts at seeding, with different mixes, Is this right?

Comment: It also occurred to me that I should've asked what kind of tree or trees are shading the ground. Could they be maples? Norway maples, perhaps?